# Template function pointer of template class - C++

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, pointer-to-member

```
template<typename C, typename Arg>
int foo(C* c, int (C::*func)(Arg), Arg a)
{
  c->*func(a);
}
```

to call the 'foo', we have to pas both A* and &A::bar,

```
foo(A*,&A::bar,var);
```

Is there a way to define the template (e.g as a struct) such that there is no need to pass "A*"? how can I define a template which gets A* from "&A::bar"?

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but perhaps [`std::is_member_function_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_function_pointer) might help a bit.

Comment: You can do `(a.*func)(a)` as well if you omit the first argument.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Thanks! but these are for C++11.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I did not get it. could you please elaborate?

Comment: If you can't use C++11, you're pretty much shooting yourself in the foot. Almost every good thing to do with templates (decltype, for example) was added in C++11.

Comment: You cannot call a member function without an object instance, are you aware of that?

Comment: @jrok: I am not doing that! I wanted to exploit A* from &A::bar. That is all

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: of course, as long as you don't work on an existing project :)

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism Then I don't see your problem. Simply use `C*` inside `func`.

Comment: There is no problem and the code works. I want to simplify it such that calling foo does not need an "A*" to be passed. a template similar to this: <tyename T*, typename T::*Func>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't avoid passing the instance if you want to call a non-static method on that instance, unless you don't mind calling it on a temporary, default-constructed instance:

```
template<typename C, typename Arg>
int call_on_temp(int (C::*func)(Arg), Arg a)
{
    C temp;
    temp.*func(a);
}
```

or the caller explicitly binds the instance into a functor:

```
template<typename F, typename Arg>
int call_on_functor(F func, Arg a)
{
    func(a);
}
```

which makes the call site ugly:

```
call_on_functor(std::bind(std::mem_fn(&Class::method), instance), arg);
```

(and you still *need* the instance, you've just moved it from one place to another).

Note that you can infer the *type* of A from the function pointer, you just can't infer an *instance to call your function on*. If you want to call a static method, you don't need the class type at all:

```
template<typename Arg>
int call_on_static(int (*func)(Arg), Arg a)
{
    func(a);
}
```

Comment: This pretty much says it all I guess. You are right. It s impossible to do it like I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This *should* do what you need it to:

```
template<typename unused>
struct member_function_pointer_type_helper;

template<typename R, typename C>
struct member_function_pointer_type_helper<R C::*> {
    typedef C type;
};

template<typename F>
struct member_function_pointer_type : member_function_pointer_type_helper<typename std::remove_cv<F>::type> {
};
```

Example:

```
struct A { void foo() { ... } };


typedef member_function_pointer_type<decltype(&A::foo)>::type a_type; // 'A'

a_type my_a;
my_a.foo();
```

This works by having a specialized template for only member functions, and then simply exports the class part of that member function.

Comment: You forgot the argument types (you specialize for data member pointer, currently). And what's the point? OP already has `C` in `func`'s template parameter list.

Comment: @jrok the OP wasn't really clear, but I interpreted it as he wanted to induce (and remove) the type of the first parameter, which is either A* or C*.

Comment: +1 Wow I'm glad I remembered using this weird syntax to define a pointer to function myself; otherwise I'd also wondered why `R C::*` matches a pointer-to-member-function. You might want to add some explanation how it works.

Comment: I m a bit lost in your code. I thought it would be pretty much straightforward. but If I cannot find another answer I will mark it as an answer. Thanks @RichardJ.RossIII. Agree with dyp. Some explanation might help a lot

Comment: @dyp I'm stumped. Why does this match a pointer to member function?

Comment: Actually guys, I'm not entirely sure why it matches the pointer-to-member. I took the documentation from `std::is_member_function_pointer`, and adapted it into this. So if someone could educate me as well, that would be great.

Comment: :D Wow it must be really obscure. Here's an example how it works: `using f_t = void(void); using ptr_t = f_t C::*; ptr_t x = &A::foo;` or similarly `using ptr_t = f_t*; void foobar(void); ptr_t x = &foobar;` I.e. you can combine the return type and the argument list.

Comment: @dyp That's slightly perverse :) TIL. And it just clicked - `R` in `R C::*` can, of course, be a function type when deduced.

Comment: @jrok Looking into the Standard, I can say *waveshands* itjustworks! (I'm not really into the syntax of declarations..) What I know is that it's an alternative style of declaring a function pointer, where you use a function type (like `void(void)`) to form a function pointer of the form `function_type declarator`.